# Create a dictionary on a list with grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I have the following object in a list:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public int GroupKey { get; set; }
    public string DemoString { get; set; }
    public object SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to create following dictionary out of it:

```
Dictionary<int, List<DemoClass>>
```

I want to group the `List<DemoClass>` by the property `GroupKey`, but I don't understand how this is done and some help.

After thinking a bit, I achieved the needed behaviour with:

```
var groupedDemoClasses = from demoClass in mySepcialVariableWhichIsAListOfDemoClass
                            group demoClass by demoClass.GroupKey
                            into groupedDemoClass
                            select groupedDemoClass;
var neededDictionary = groupedDemoClass.ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

but, is there a way to make this into a single statement?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
var groupedDemoClasses = (from demoClass in mySepcialVariableWhichIsAListOfDemoClass
                          group demoClass by demoClass.GroupKey
                          into groupedDemoClass
                          select groupedDemoClass).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

This one will work !!!

Answer (score 221):

Just to make [mquander's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938040/what-linq-statement-to-create-a-dictionary-on-a-list-with-group/938069#938069) concrete:

```
var groupedDemoClasses = mySpecialVariableWhichIsAListOfDemoClass
                             .GroupBy(x => x.GroupKey)
                             .ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

You'd make it shorter if you used shorter variable names too, of course :)

However, might I suggest that a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) might be more appropriate? A Lookup is basically a dictionary from a key to an `IEnumerable<T>` - unless you really *need* the values as a list, it makes the code even shorter (and more efficient) with the [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) call:

```
var groupedDemoClasses = mySpecialVariableWhichIsAListOfDemoClass
                             .ToLookup(x => x.GroupKey);
```

Comment: i thought that a lookup performs not that good, compared to a built dictionary, in a longterm-environment, due it builds up the result fresh for every request... please correct me, if i'm wrong!

Comment: No, it creates the whole lookup. In general, ToXXX doesn't use deferred execution.

Comment: (You may be thinking of a Grouping, which is indeed deferred.)

Comment: If I wasn't so spiteful I'd vote you up. Came for the Linq, stayed for the data structure I've never heard of!

Comment: This was particularly useful because I, like so many others did not even know about the Lookup data structure.  But the really helpful piece of this was you took the trouble to add the link to the MS documentation so I could really see what it is.

Comment: This was helpful in the performance aspect as well.. groupby + todictionary was costly. I'm wondering why there is no  trygetvalue  in lookup ?

Comment: @sasikt: The model is that you can look up *anything*, and you just get an empty collection if the key doesn't exist. That's often more useful than the TryGetValue approach, IMO.

Comment: my bad. I dint notice that lookup[notexistingkey] returns an empty list and doesnt throw an exception. thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You already made it a one-liner.  Just put the `ToDictionary` at the end of your first line.  If you want it to be shorter, use the functional composition syntax instead of the query syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going *slightly* off topic here, but I got to this thread becausde I was looking for a way to create a dictionary of a dictionary in Linq, and the conversation here lead me to the answer...

You *can* use linq to create multi-level dictionaries, which is useful for scenarios where you've got more than 1 key or dimension that you want to search by. The trick is to create a grouping and then convert it to a dictionary, as follows:

```
  Dim qry = (From acs In ActualSales _
             Group By acs.ProductID Into Group _
             Select ProductID, Months = Group.ToDictionary(Function(c) c.Period) _
            ).ToDictionary(Function(c) c.ProductID)
```

The resulting query can be used as follows:

```
 If qry.ContainsKey(_ProductID) Then
      With qry(_ProductID)
          If .Months.ContainsKey(_Period) Then
             ...
          End If
      End With
 End If
```

Hope this is helpful to anyone else who needs this sort of query.