# Linq: Convert list of object to dictionary, with an object member as value

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0

I have a class like:

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    public guid Group { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

contained in:

```
IEnumerable<ContainerClass>
```

How do I convert it to the following dictionary?

```
Dictionary<guid, List<int>>
```

I've looked at similar questions (eg. 
[Create a dictionary on a list with grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938040/what-linq-statement-to-create-a-dictionary-on-a-list-with-group)) but that goes to `Dictionary<guid, List<ContainerClass>>` which is different from what I'd like.

I know I can do a secondary linq query to just get the value entries after I have an IEnumerable but that seems messy; it seems like there should be a way to do this directly in a single statement.

Edit: Note, I'm aware of Lookup(), but in this case, I am actually doing bulk processing by Group, so I really do need the Dictionary (or something where each group has a collection of Values). In this case, each Group is being sent to a resource, and I want to send all the values for that resource in bulk: if I have 10 groups, with 50 values each (500 entries in my List total), I want to make 10 calls.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than a `Dictionary<Guid, List<int>>` could you use a `Lookup<Guid, int>`? That would make it easy:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Group, x => x.Value);
```

A [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) is much like a `Dictionary`, but designed to work with multiple values per key. On interesting difference is that if you fetch a missing key, you'll just get an empty sequence back instead of an exception.

*If* you can use that, that's great. Otherwise you could always convert from a `Lookup` to a `Dictionary`:

```
var dictionary = list.ToLookup(x => x.Group, x => x.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToList());
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you have multiple instances of the class, otherwise it is trivial. In LINQ, something similar is:

```
var lookup = data.ToLookup(obj => obj.Group, obj => obj.Value);
```

Then you can, for example:

```
foreach(var value in lookup[someGuid]) {
    ...
}
```

If you really need this as a dictionary (rather than a lookup, which is close):

```
var lookup = data.GroupBy(obj => obj.Group).ToDictionary(
          grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(obj => obj.Value).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Given an `IEnumerable<ContainerClass> named objects`, you could do this:

```
var dict = objects
    .ToLookup(o => o.Group)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(o => o.Value).ToList());
```

Explanation:

`ToLookup` method converts the `IEnumerable<ContainerClass>` to an `ILookup<Guid, ContainerClass>`.  The `ToDictionary` method then takes the collection of `IGrouping<Guid, ContainerClass>` objects, and selects the `Key` of the grouping as the key for the dictionary, and then selects the `Value` property of the `ContainerClass` objects, and converts that to a `List<int>` for the dictionary values.

You may not actually need a `Dictionary<ContainerClass>`.  If you're OK with using an `ILookup<Guid, int>` instead, you can just do this:

```
var lookup = objects.ToLookup(o => o.Group, o => o.Value);
```